# To pass an array by reference in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, reference

I am trying to modify this merge sort codes from GeekstoGeeks with passing an array by reference.

```
/* C program for Merge Sort */
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

// Merges two subarrays of arr[]. 
// First subarray is arr[l..m] 
// Second subarray is arr[m+1..r] 
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) 
{ 
    int i, j, k; 
    int n1 = m - l + 1; 
    int n2 = r - m; 

    /* create temp arrays */
    int L[n1], R[n2]; 

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
        L[i] = arr[l + i]; 
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) 
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j]; 

    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray 
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray 
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray 
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) { 
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) { 
            arr[k] = L[i]; 
            i++; 
        } 
        else { 
            arr[k] = R[j]; 
            j++; 
        } 
        k++; 
    } 

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there 
    are any */
    while (i < n1) { 
        arr[k] = L[i]; 
        i++; 
        k++; 
    } 

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there 
    are any */
    while (j < n2) { 
        arr[k] = R[j]; 
        j++; 
        k++; 
    } 
} 

/* l is for left index and r is right index of the 
sub-array of arr to be sorted */
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) 
{ 
    if (l < r) { 
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for 
        // large l and h 
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2; 

        // Sort first and second halves 
        mergeSort(arr, l, m); 
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r); 

        merge(arr, l, m, r); 
    } 
} 

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int A[], int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", A[i]); 
    printf("\n"); 
} 

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = { 12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7 }; 
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 

    printf("Given array is \n"); 
    printArray(arr, arr_size); 

    mergeSort(arr, 0, arr_size - 1); 

    printf("\nSorted array is \n"); 
    printArray(arr, arr_size); 
    return 0; 
}
```

To something like this:

```
void mergeSort(int* arr[], int l, int r);
void merge(int* arr[], int l, int m, int r);
```

I thought it is a simple task because I could simply change every arr to *arr in the functions to dereference them. The program is still runnable but gives me a bunch of unknown numbers.

Then I searched the stack overflow until I see this post:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751409/swapping-2-arrays-in-c#:~:text=Since%20pointer%20is%2064%20bit,two%20int%20which%20get%20swapped.&text=In%20C%20an%20array%20is,they%20are%20pointers%20to%20arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751409/swapping-2-arrays-in-c#:%7E:text=Since%20pointer%20is%2064%20bit,two%20int%20which%20get%20swapped.&text=In%20C%20an%20array%20is,they%20are%20pointers%20to%20arrays)

It also passes an array by reference. (int* a and int* b)

```
void swapArray( int *a, int *b, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

But in reverse, when I change it to

```
void swapArray( int a, int b, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, again. Could someone explain to me why and how can I modify my merge sort codes properly? Or where I should look for? I am so confused about this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you're missing is that arrays **cannot** be passed by value in C. They are always passed as a pointer to the first element. So `foo(int array[])` is exactly the same as `foo(int *array)`. But `foo(int *array[])` is something else entirely, and not what you want. On the other hand, with `bar(int a)`,  `a` *is* passed by value, whereas with `bar(int *a)`,  a pointer to `a` is passed to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int *arr[]` is an array of pointers. Or rather it's a pointer to a pointer (it's really `int **arr`).

To pass a pointer to an array (which almost never is needed) you need e.g. `int (*arr) [6]`. And yes, the size of the array is then mandatory (variable-length arrays are valid).

But as I said, passning pointers to arrays is almost never needed, because arrays naturally decays to pointers (to their first element).

And as an argument declaration `int arr[]` is equal to `int *arr`.

That is, with

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
```

you already pass the array by "reference".

Comment: Re “And yes, the size of the array is then mandatory…”: No, it is not. You may have a pointer to an incomplete type. Further, it may be accessed as OP wants, via `(*arr)[i]`, although not with `arr[0][i]`.

Answer (score 1):

The subscript operator, `[ ]`, has higher precedence than the dereference operator, `*`. So `int *arr[]` declares `arr` to be an array of pointers to `int`. To make it a pointer to an array, you need `int (*arr)[]`.

Similarly, in expressions, `*arr[3]` attempts to take element 3 of an array `arr` and dereference it. Instead you need `(*arr)[3]` to use `*arr` to get the array and then `[3]` to get element 3.