# error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[4]’ to ‘int**’ | SWAPPING ARRAYS

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, swap

I am trying to write a function that swap two arrays in O(1) time complexity. However, when i try to write the function parameters, I get the error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[4]’ to ‘int**’
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void swap_array_by_ptr(int* a[], int* b[]) {
    int* temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int fr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int rv[] = {4,3,2,1};
    
    swap_array_by_ptr(&fr, &rv);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
        cout << fr[i] << " ";
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
        cout << rv[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

However, when i tried to define the arrays with 'new' command, this works as expected as below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void swap_array_by_ptr(int** a, int** b) {
    int* temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int fr = new int[4]{1,2,3,4};
    int rv = new int[4]{4,3,2,1};
    
    swap_array_by_ptr(&fr, &rv);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
        cout << fr[i] << " ";
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
        cout << rv[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Is there any way that i can define the arrays with [] method and swap the arrays by sending these arrays with '&array' method ?

As I believe, there must be a way to do that, I only achieve this when I'm trying to do with 'new' method. However, is there any way to swap two arrays in O(1) complexity with sending parameters as
swap_array_by_ptr(&fr, &rv);
?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can't swap this type of array. Also `c++` and `c` are different languages. Had you used std::array<> which is the c++ array you can swap that.

Comment: I appreciate your attention Sir, could you please check the edited version of my question ? I edited the correct version of the code where i defined arrays with new keyword. Please, check again.

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are arrays of arrays, not arrays of pointers.

Comment: This code isn't *really* swapping the arrays at all.  It's swapping two pointers.

Comment: I also want to say that my purpose is writing a function for this operation and I need this to happen in O(1) complexity, I guess the std::array<> iterates the array for the operation, so the complexity must be O(n).

Comment: @Eljay I completely agree with you, this is OK for this case, however, is there any way to use the array as a pointer than swap two pointer for arrays ? As i did in the second (correct) version.

Comment: A C-style array is not a pointer.  It's an array.  C-style arrays *decay* into pointers to their first element, for your convenience, but that's just a helpful language behavior.  (That helpful behavior can be a bit of a puzzler once you realize that it is happening, and until you've internalized why it is happening.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not swap two arrays with O( 1 ). You need to swap each pairs of corresponding elements of two arrays.

In the first program

```
int fr[] = {1,2,3,4};
int rv[] = {4,3,2,1};

swap_array_by_ptr(&fr, &rv);
```

the expressions `&fr` and `&rv` have type `int( * )[4]` while the corresponding function parameters in fact has the type `int **`

```
void swap_array_by_ptr(int* a[], int* b[]) {
```

after adjusting the parameters having array types to pointers to the array element types by the compiler.

So the compiler issues an error.

You could use standard function `std::swap` declared in the header `<utility>` the following way

```
std::swap( fr, rv );
```

But in any case its complexity is O( n ).

In the second program there are at least typos. Instead of

```
int fr = new int[4]{1,2,3,4};
int rv = new int[4]{4,3,2,1};
```

you have to write

```
int *fr = new int[4]{1,2,3,4};
int *rv = new int[4]{4,3,2,1};
```

In this case you are not swapping arrays themselves. That is the arrays will still store their initial values. You are swapping pointers that point to the dynamically allocated arrays.

To be sure that arrays are not swapped consider the following demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void swap_array_by_ptr(int** a, int** b) {
    int* temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int fr[] = { 1,2,3,4};
    int rv[] = {4,3,2,1};

    int *p1 = fr;
    int *p2 = rv;
    
    swap_array_by_ptr( &p1, &p2 );
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
        cout << p1[i] << " ";
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
        cout << p2[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
        cout << fr[i] << " ";
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
        cout << rv[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for typo warning Sir, I made these typos while writing question into here. I got the idea. Do you mean that assuming that i have corrected my typos in second version, the only way to swap two arrays in O(1) complexity is using pointer and the function for this is the one in the second version ? I mean, there is no way to swap two arrays, literally arrays and not pointers, with O(1) complexity, right ?

Comment: You could use `std::vector<int>` and swapping that is O(1): [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap2)

Comment: @yildomer Yes you can not swap arrays with O( 1 ). You can swap pointers that point to arrays with O( 1 ). The array themselves will be unchanged.

Comment: I know the idea of vectors but i did not prefer to use them in this case Sir. Instead, i guess you understood my purpose. "I mean, there is no way to swap two arrays, literally arrays and not pointers, with O(1) complexity, right ?"

Comment: There is no way to do what you want if you want to stick to just arrays.

Comment: @drescherjm I appreciate your time and effort Sir, i got it, thank you.

Comment: Can't I create pointers for the arrays I defined as {int fr[] = { 1,2,3,4};} and then swap the pointers ? I mean, I am trying to apply the function that I wrote in second version but defining with fr[] method. I am asking that creating pointers for the array i defined then swapping pointers, not directly swapping arrays ?

Comment: @yildomer Arrays themselves are not swapped if you are swapping pointers to them.

Comment: Okay but let's say I want to use only the pointers to do some operations on an array, and I want to swap these two pointers. My question is creating a pointer in a such way that I would be able to swap these pointers ? But, I want to define the arrays as [] method.

Comment: @yildomer As I showed in the demonstration program you can introduce pointers like int fr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; int *p = fr; In thi case the pointer p will point to the first element of the array fr.

Comment: Got the logic behind it Sir, thanks for patience.  :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a syntactic quirk inherited from C that a declaration of a function parameter as an array is automatically converted to a declaration as a corresponding pointer.  This is not as odd as it might first seem, however, because it dovetails with the automatic conversion of function *arguments* of array type to corresponding pointers, also inherited from C.<sup>*</sup>

Thus, this declaration ...

> ```
> void swap_array_by_ptr(int* a[], int* b[]) {
> ```

... is equivalent to this one:

```
void swap_array_by_ptr(int **a, int **b) {
```

.  But the arguments you are passing do not match.  This, for example,

> ```
>     int fr[] = {1,2,3,4};
> ```

declares `fr` as an array of 4 `int`.  If it were passed as a function argument, it would be automatically converted to a pointer to the first element, thus of type `int *`.  Types `int *` and `int **` are not compatible.

On the other hand, what you actually try to pass, `&fr` is the address of an array 4 `int`, of type `int(*)[4]`.  This also is incompatible with `int **`, because arrays are not pointers.

You could write your function like this:

```
void swap_array_by_ptr(int (*a)[4], int (*b)[4]) {
    int temp[4];
    memcpy(temp, a, sizeof(a));
    memcpy(a, b, sizeof(b));
    memcpy(b, temp, sizeof(temp));
}
```

That would be compatible with the call in your code.  Do note, however, that that is specific to array size 4, and you're not really gaining anything useful from that.  You could, however, convert it to a template:

```
template<class T, std::size_t n>
void swap_array(T (*a)[n], T (*b)[n]) {
    T temp[n];

    memcpy(temp, a, sizeof(a));
    memcpy(a, b, sizeof(b));
    memcpy(b, temp, sizeof(temp));
}
```

That handles arrays of any element type and size,<sup>**</sup> as long as the sizes match.  Of course, it scales as O(N) with array size, in both time and auxiliary space.

Such time scaling is unavoidable.  To swap two objects you need to read each at least once and write each at least once, and that requires time proportional to the size of the objects.  But you could reduce the space overhead to O(1) by swapping the arrays element by element in a loop.  That would very likely be slower, but the time complexity would still be O(N).

Of course, you can also use `std::swap()` on arrays.  It is quite similar to the template above, but uses references to the arrays instead of pointers to them.

---

<sup>*</sup>This is a specific case of a much more general behavior.
<sup>**</sup>So long as the temporary array does not turn out to be too large for the stack.

Comment: Wow, Sir, it is different point of view, unfortunately, I assumed that if 'fr' is converting to int* automatically, getting address of it by & operator, will generate int** type, but it didn't, as you said. Why did not it happen ? Can you please explain it more ?

Comment: @yildomer, one of the few exceptions to arrays being automatically converted to pointers is when they are the operand of the address-of operator (unary `&`).  There's not really any more to it than that that's the rule.

Comment: As you said Sir, thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score -1):

Change the swap_array_by_ptr function from 'swap_array_by_ptr(int** a, int** b)'
to 'swap_array_by_ptr(int* a, int* b)'.

```cpp
void swap_array_by_ptr(int* a, int* b) {
    int* temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

here's a link to a similar question: [Swapping 2 arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751409/swapping-2-arrays-in-c)

Comment: No way Sir, {int* temp = *a;} in this line, you attempt to assign an integer to a pointer. This generates an error. Additionally, the question is not similar.